# Can I get a trigger to run in sheets based on a specific number being added to a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to trigger a function if a specific number is added to a cell.
When the number 25 is added to a cell (ideally E2), function 25 will  run
.  If the number 20 is added function 20 will run, etc.

```
function _25() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').setFormula('=(D2)/4');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E3').setFormula('=(D3)/4');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E4').setFormula('=(D4)/4');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E5').setFormula('=(D5)/4');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E6').setFormula('=(D6)/4')
  };

  function _20(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').setFormula('=(D2)/5');  
  spreadsheet.getRange('E3').setFormula('=(D3)/5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E4').setFormula('=(D4)/5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E5').setFormula('=(D5)/5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E6').setFormula('=(D6)/5');
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NO but you can get an onEdit trigger by editing a cell and it can call a function based upon the value in a cell.  But the edit must be done by a user, not a script or formula making the edit.

Comment: I should have worded better - I want to trigger to run if the end user enters the number. I can't figure out how to make the triggers work based on what the number IS, as opposed to something being added to the cell at all.

Comment: The it sounds like you can use an onEdit trigger. Here's the event object: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if( sh.getName() == 'Sheetname' && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == 25) {
    _25();//E2
  }
}
```